# Firestore rules: resource.data.displayName getting undefained

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to set some rules when someone reading there documents, but `resource.data.displayName` I use for but on console it shows up that the `displayName` is undefined field, but actually the `displayName` is already defined in firestore database.
Here is the [firestore roles picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiWZI.png), Check out line 9.
And here is my [firestore users/Document picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W425o.png).

Comment: You are talking about `displayName` but in your picture line 9 I can see you are using `userId`. Can you please check and be more accurate?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, rules, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Lastly, images and links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Also, take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sorry I am actually about userId, (replace the displayName as userId in the abouve message)

Comment: Noted, I will paste a code, not pictures, Thank you!